# Definition of embedded and immersed curve

Tags: differential-geometry

What does it mean to say that a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is embedded? I think a curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is embedded if it lies on a plane, but what does it mean in 2d? I searched everywhere but I can't find an answer.

Also, is there a simple way of seeing an immersive curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Thanks

Comment: The difference between an immersion and an embedding is that the former does not need to be injective. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_%28mathematics%29

Comment: Also, even when an immersion is injective, it need not be a homeomorphism onto its image.

Comment: And a curve embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$ need not lie on a plane - for example, a helix.

Answer (score 14):

In the smooth context, an embedding is a diffeomorphism onto its image. A curve in $\mathbb R^2$ is really a smooth map  $\gamma:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2$. This map must have a smooth inverse $\gamma^{-1}: \gamma(\mathbb R)\to \mathbb R$ in order for the curve to be embedded. In particular, this requires $\gamma'$ to be nonzero (otherwise the inverse can't be smooth). 
An embedded curve can look like this:

[image: embedded]

Having an immersed curve asks *only*  for nonzero derivative. Being a diffeomorphism is not required. An immersed curve can look like this:

[image: immersed]

To make the distinction trickier, an injective immersion can fail to be an embedding. (As Zhen Lin said.) The figure below shows an immersed line: the immersion is such that the limits $\lim_{t\to \pm\infty}\gamma(t)$ are the "intersectinn" point. There is no actual intersection: the curve passes through the center of the figure only once. This is an injective immersion. Not an embedding, because the inverse map $\gamma^{-1}$ is not even continuous.

[image: injective immersion]

> I think a curve in $\mathbb R^3$ is embedded if it lies on a plane

This is totally wrong (as Neal pointed out). Being embedded into *any* space means the same thing: diffeomorphism onto the image. Or homeomorphism, when we are in the topological setting.

Comment: Heuristically can it be said that a continuous curve which lies in each quadrants of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is immersed in $\mathbb{R}^2$?. or atleast something which can be translated around the origin in such a way that it lies in all the four quadrants of $\mathbb{R}^2$?.

Comment: Doesn't an immersed curve require injective derivative not necessarily nonzero?

Comment: In the last picture, how to show $\gamma^{-1}$ is not even continuous ?